# Inconsistent free space reported

Tags: windows-7, disk-space

- Windows 7.
- 4TB drive.
- Some programs are reporting just over 1 GB free, and others are
  reporting almost 6 GB free.
- System protection off.

---

[image: explorer screenshot] (1 GB)

---

`fsutil volume diskfree d:` (1 GB):

```
Total # of free bytes        : 1312534528
Total # of bytes             : 4000650883072
Total # of avail free bytes  : 1312534528
```

---

`fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo d:`:

```
NTFS Volume Serial Number :       <REDACTED>
Version :                         3.1
Number Sectors :                  0x00000001d1bcafff
Total Clusters :                  0x000000003a3795ff
Free Clusters  :                  0x00000000001787fb
Total Reserved :                  0x000000000012a040
Bytes Per Sector  :               512
Bytes Per Cluster :               4096
Bytes Per FileRecord Segment    : 1024
Clusters Per FileRecord Segment : 0
Mft Valid Data Length :           0x0000000002700000
Mft Start Lcn  :                  0x00000000000c0000
Mft2 Start Lcn :                  0x0000000000000002
Mft Zone Start :                  0x00000000316d7f40
Mft Zone End   :                  0x00000000316db960
RM Identifier:                    <REDACTED>
```

(Free Clusters: 1787fb = 1,542,139 X 4096 = 6,316,601,344 bytes = 5.88 GB)

(Total Reserved: 12a040 = 1,220,672 X 4096 = 4,999,872,512 bytes = 4.66 GB)

(Free Clusters - Total Reserved = 1.22 GB)

This seems to explain the inconsistencies, but I don't know what "Total Reserved" means.

---

`ntfsinfo -nobanner d` (6 GB):

```
Volume Size
-----------
Volume size            : 3815317 MB
Total sectors          : 7813771263
Total clusters         : 976721407
Free clusters          : 1542139
Free space             : 6023 MB (0% of drive)

Allocation Size
----------------
Bytes per sector       : 512
Bytes per cluster      : 4096
Bytes per MFT record   : 0
Clusters per MFT record: 0

MFT Information
---------------
MFT size               : 39 MB (0% of drive)
MFT start cluster      : 786432
MFT zone clusters      : 829259584 - 829274464
MFT zone size          : 58 MB (0% of drive)
MFT mirror start       : 2

Meta-Data files
---------------
```

---

chkdsk event log (6 GB):

```
Chkdsk was executed in read-only mode on a volume snapshot.  

Checking file system on D:

CHKDSK is verifying files (stage 1 of 3)...
  39936 file records processed.                                          File verification completed.
  88 large file records processed.                                      0 bad file records processed.                                        0 EA records processed.                                              0 reparse records processed.                                       CHKDSK is verifying indexes (stage 2 of 3)...
  48552 index entries processed.                                         Index verification completed.


CHKDSK is verifying security descriptors (stage 3 of 3)...
  39936 file SDs/SIDs processed.                                         Cleaning up 2 unused index entries from index $SII of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 2 unused index entries from index $SDH of file 0x9.
Cleaning up 2 unused security descriptors.
Security descriptor verification completed.
  4309 data files processed.                                            CHKDSK is verifying Usn Journal...
  176992 USN bytes processed.                                             Usn Journal verification completed.
Windows has checked the file system and found no problems.

   3815317 MB total disk space.
   3809372 MB in 35258 files.
     22108 KB in 4310 indexes.
    225647 KB in use by the system.
     65536 KB occupied by the log file.
   5840876 KB available on disk.

      4096 bytes in each allocation unit.
 976721407 total allocation units on disk.
   1460219 allocation units available on disk.
```

---

`defrag d: /A /V` (6 GB):

```
Microsoft Disk Defragmenter
Copyright (c) 2007 Microsoft Corp.

Invoking analysis on (D:)...



The operation completed successfully.

Post Defragmentation Report:


    Volume Information:
        Volume size                 = 3.63 TB
        Cluster size                = 4 KB
        Used space                  = 3.63 TB
        Free space                  = 5.88 GB


    Fragmentation:
        Total fragmented space      = 0%
        Average fragments per file  = 1.09

        Movable files and folders   = 40676
        Unmovable files and folders = 10


    Files:
        Fragmented files            = 289
        Total file fragments        = 491


    Folders:
        Total folders               = 4310
        Fragmented folders          = 0
        Total folder fragments      = 0


    Free space:
        Free space count            = 964
        Average free space size     = 6.18 MB
        Largest free space size     = 55.76 MB


    Master File Table (MFT):
        MFT size                    = 39.00 MB
        MFT record count            = 39935
        MFT usage                   = 100%
        Total MFT fragments         = 2

    Note: File fragments larger than 64MB are not included in the fragmentation statistics.


    You do not need to defragment this volume.
```

---

`dir` (1 GB):

```
 Volume in drive D has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is <REDACTED>

 Directory of D:\

08/05/2017  02:34 PM    <DIR>          <REDACTED>
02/13/2017  08:58 PM    <DIR>          <REDACTED>
06/29/2017  06:18 AM    <DIR>          <REDACTED>
06/30/2017  01:50 AM    <DIR>          <REDACTED>
10/27/2016  01:42 AM    <DIR>          <REDACTED>
               0 File(s)              0 bytes
               5 Dir(s)   1,312,534,528 bytes free
```

Why do some programs report more and some less free space?

EDIT: [windirstat (run as system with `PsExec.exe -i -s -d`)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H32es.png)

EDIT2: Does anyone know what "Total Reserved" from `fsutil fsinfo ntfsinfo d:` means? Pretty sure it has something to do with that.

Comment: I would suggest checking with your motherboard manufacturer to see if there are updates or drivers required to mount high volume drives.  My last computer required both a bios update and a custom app (driver) before it would address drives of 3TB or higher.

Comment: Drive is recognized just fine. It has been in the computer from brand new (full format) to almost 4 TB filled now. Have had no problems. Just trying to figure out why explorer says 1 GB free and chkdsk says 6 GB free.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I visualize the file system usage on Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8248/how-can-i-visualize-the-file-system-usage-on-windows)

Comment: "Why do some programs report more and some less free space?" - How much space will depend on the permissions the program's process was ran at.

Comment: I've tried running windirstat and treesize as admin and even as system via psexec, but still can't find the missing 5 GB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess at the fact that some of these programs are able to view hidden folder, while others might not be. A lot of this space may be your pagefile.sys, swapfile.sys, hiberfil.sys, etc.

Some of the programs you used to search are able to see this file. Others might not be able to. Most Windows programs are unable to see some .sys files so report open space where there may not be any.

EDIT: I was wrong. This space is reserved on NTFS drives for MFT (Master File Table) expansion. You cannot use it. It is there, but not available for your usage. I wouldn't use NTFS for this type of drive for this exact reason. After re-reading, I noticed I skipped over your ntfsinfo log and your napkin math. You have 1.2 GB of space remaining for your use, PERIOD.

Comment: This is a separate storage drive so it shouldn't have any system files on it. Pagefile is disabled on it and I have hibernation disabled on my system. The recycle bin is empty and system protection is turned off on the drive.

Comment: Try running Windirstat on the drive, see how much space that returns

Comment: Please see my edit.

Comment: Windows, although System Protection is disabled, seems to still create a System Restore file. See here: https://superuser.com/questions/1118614/windows-10-reporting-wrong-hard-disk-free-space

Comment: Disabled system protection again and deleted all restore points. It says current usage is 0 bytes. Ran windirstat as system with psexec, still showing 5 GB <Unknown>.

Comment: Try a variant of WinDirStat known to display the files that WinDirStat cannot access: http://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free/

Comment: Also, it would be EXTREMELY helpful to know what this drive is used for

Comment: Drive is used for general storage. Stuff that I download, movies, music, files from older computers, pictures from cameras, important documents, etc. [treesize run as admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smi8X.png)

Comment: Set the units to GB and resend it please..

Comment: [done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gtm1u.png)

Comment: Ok so there's a little bit of a discrepancy. temp_downloads appears to take up 63.1% of the drive (according to TreeSize). temp_downloads appears to take up 62.9% according to WinDirStat

Comment: How much RAM do you have in this system..?

Comment: 16GB. When I disable "show free space" and "show unknown" windirstat looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0QErG.png)

Comment: I know you don't think it's a pagefile, but how large is your pagefile?

Comment: `17,130,004,480 pagefile.sys` but it's on my C:

Comment: What about hiberfil and swapfile?

Comment: Don't see any other files in c: root when doing `dir /A` only folders and pagefile.sys. Running Windows 7 btw.

Comment: Read my edit, please.

Comment: which one are you talking about?

Comment: Just read the paragraph at the end of my answer.

Comment: I see it now. Thanks. I figured it might be related to that, but isn't 4.66 GB kinda excessive when I'm only using 39 MB for MFT according to ntfsinfo?