# TEMP folder filling up with AppX files and canot be stopped

Tags: windows-10

Yesterday I found my C: drive had suddenly filled up due to 80 GB appearing in C:\Window\TEMP. There were three types of files and about 13,000 of each of them.

AppXDeploymentServer_B1874DF3-7BCE-0006-9D58-88B1CE7BD401 
AppxErrorReport_B1874DF3-7BCE-0007-FF72-88B1CE7BD401.txt
AppXPackaging_B1874DF3-7BCE-0007-FF72-88B1CE7BD401.evtx

Possibly connected with last night's WU to 1803 (OS Build 17134.407).

I deleted all of the files and they stopped.

But as I feared, after a reboot this morning **they are being downloaded again at a rate of every second or so**.

In Services I found AppX Deployment Service (AppXSVC): 
*"Provides infrastructure support for deploying Store applications. This
service is started on demand and if disabled Store applications will not
be deployed to the system, and may not function properly."*

It is enabled and set to Manual. But it cannot be stopped or disabled, at least without deleting some of its upstream dependencies, which I'm not going to attempt:
[Screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3argca7843sxfdt/Appx-1.jpg?raw=1)

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix the issue without major side effects please?

Terry, East Grinstead, UK

Comment: Related: https://superuser.com/questions/1371229/low-disk-space-after-filling-up-c-windows-temp-with-evtx-and-txt-files

Answer (score 3):

You can disable the broken Windows Store service by hacking it to Disabled.

Win+R

regedit.exe

Yes run as Administrator

Navigate to
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\AppXSvc

Double-click the Start key inside it

Change the value to a 4 (which means Disabled for Services)

Restart

When I disabled this, AppXSvc was dumping 1gb of files to my disk every hour, running me out of disk every few days.

Answer (score 1):

Of the various steps I tried I think this [using Settings > Privacy](https://www.cnet.com/forums/discussions/temporary-files-on-windows-10-keep-filling-up/) was the one that fixed it. I disabled about 90% of the apps there, i.e. those I don't use or anticipate using. Of course, another reboot might re-trigger the issue...

Answer (score 0):

This may happen when Windows Update has broken some installed application
from the Microsoft Store, and the Store is striving mightily to correct
the problem.

I would suggest :

- First wait patiently a few days to see if the Store will manage to
  stabilize the situation.
- Run
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).
- For applications that are not working, see Microsoft's
  [Fix problems with apps from Microsoft Store](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4027498/microsoft-store-fix-problems-with-apps)
- To reinstall everything see
  [How To Reinstall Store And Other Preinstalled Apps In Windows 10](https://www.intowindows.com/how-to-reinstall-store-and-other-preinstalled-apps-in-windows-10/)
- If your disk is filling up with these files and there is no end in sight,
  perform a
  [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: I'd meanwhile ran sfc, with no errors. Your likely diagnosis squares with my research. Another possible clue: Cortana is not working. Its icon is present but no process in TM.

Comment: I added a 3rd and 4th point.