# Windows 10:"Temporary files" suddenly taking up as much space as "Apps & features", but can't delete

Tags: hard-drive, temporary-files, windows-10-v1909

I'm running Windows 10 version 1909, OS build 18363.900.

After upgrading my Win 10 version, my HDD has been almost full, degrading performance.  I now have about 40MB free on my 436 GB C:\ drive (my main partition).

System \ Storage says that I have 134 GB in "Temporary files", the same as the 134 GB in "Apps & features".  (Before the upgrade, I had about 100 - 200 GB free.)

Opening "Temporary files" only shows 1-2 GB of files (which I do not want to delete).

Thus, it looks like "Temporary files" might be mirroring "Apps & features", but in a way that I can't disable/delete.

I've deleted C:\Windows.old.  This initially gave me about 10 GB free, but it's filled up again.  Disk Cleanup and malware scans don't find anything.

**WinDirStat** (suggested by @RamHound) shows a 10 GB **C:$Recycle.bin** with directories like S-1-5-... that I can't delete.  It also shows an 132 GB **C:\Windows\Temp<Files>** directory containing .evtx files like Microsoft-Windows-Store_Operational_... which I can't even find in Windows Explorer, let alone delete.  These two directories seem to be the problem.

Comment: I found WizTree more useful as it allowed me to bulk delete the .evtx and .txt files filling my Temp directory. I also followed the accepted answer at https://superuser.com/questions/1371229/low-disk-space-after-filling-up-c-windows-temp-with-evtx-and-txt-files to stop new .evtx and .txt files.  Can you submit an answer mentioning these for me to accept?

Comment: I can flag this as a duplicate. I don’t submit answers to duplicate questions

Comment: thanks @Ramhound: I don't want to accept this as a pure duplicate, as I needed to work across two previous questions.  If you didn't want to submit an answer referring to these, do you mind if I do?

Comment: A question can be closed for being a duplicate of multiple questions

Answer (score 0):

i was getting that problem, to fix it open cmd as Administrator just type: Takeown /f (location of temp files here)
after it says "operation success" ,go and delete the temp files

Comment: thanks @Te9hira TM: I don't know how to find the temp files that System/Storage tells me I have as I can't see them when I open "Temporary files".

Comment: press windows key + r and then type temp and then delete everything when you done press win key + r again and type %temp% and then delete everything (after you type the command of course)

Comment: also did you check show cached folders in folder options?

Comment: I think so: in Windows Explorer, I was trying to show everything I could.  For whatever reason, WinDirStat and WizTree were more useful.