# Available space in Windows 11 is very small

Tags: hard-drive, windows-11

I have Windows 11 Pro. When I select all files ( including hidden ), and calculate their size, I see 247 Gb. But my drive has 2 Tb. I can't understand, why 1.6 Tb become invisible for the windows.
[image: All files]

any guidance on how can I find what else eaten space? Drive is bitlocked.

Disk managment shows following:
[image]

And properties of C drive shows this:

[image: c drive properties]

Also want to mention, that I tried chkdsk c: /f /r /x
but it didn't change anything. Recycle bin is also empty.

Comment: Does the hidden files including the "System Files" which is hidden even further? (under File explorer - options - Hide Protected Operating System Files)

Comment: Not sure I understand the question. If you open the file explorer menu, right-click on your C drive, click properties, then what does it show?

Comment: Can you edit your question and add a screenshot of Disk Management to see the drive and partition details?

Comment: @YisroelTech done

Comment: Great, but can you put a full screenshot where you also see the reported Free Space on top?

Comment: @YisroelTech total sum of all files is less then 300 Gb, which is much smaller then total capacity of the hard drive

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows 10 reporting wrong hard disk free space](https://superuser.com/questions/1118614/windows-10-reporting-wrong-hard-disk-free-space)

Comment: @JoepvanSteen no it does not. WinDirStat, ChkDsk, showing hidden and system didn't show missing files, but TreeSize Free showed

Comment: @YuriyZaletskyy, yeah I found TreeSize to be much more effective. Which files were they?

Comment: @YisroelTech MS SQL Server dump files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your C: partition with [**TreeSize Free**](https://www.jam-software.com/treesize_free?ca=1).

Make sure to run the program as administrator.