# Disk space not freeing after deleting Windows.old with Disk Cleanup

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, ssd

I just installed windows on a brand new SSD and decided that I should remove the old Windows installation from the old drive that I wasn't using for windows anymore.

- I renamed the Windows folder to Windows.old on the old drive.
- I ran the Disk Cleanup as administrator and selected the drive I wasn't using for windows anymore.
- I Selected "Previous Windows installation(s)" and ran the Disk Cleanup

After the cleanup was complete I checked how much more free space I got. None. In fact I lost free space 100mb. Then I checked if the Windows.old folder was still there, it wasn't and neither was any kind of Windows folder. I checked trash can from the computers own and from the drive itself, I checked every folder in the drive that could be more than 20gb in hope of finding the Windows folder with no success.

Also when checking from storage usage settings, it shows that windows would be still in the old drive.

Where did the Windows folder go and how do I remove it completely from the drive?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Missing disk space in Windows XP](https://superuser.com/questions/212647/missing-disk-space-in-windows-xp)

Comment: Your question lacks some crucial details... if you installed/re-installed Windows to partition with an existing Windows install, the installer will automatically place everything in the root of the partition into a directory called `Windows.old`... please elaborate on what occurred.

Comment: I installed windows to a brand new drive and wanted to remove windows from the old drive that I wasn't using for windows anymore to free up some space from it (Edited the post)

Comment: "I renamed the Windows folder to Windows.old on the old drive." <-- This is not a correct process. Windows.old contains a complete installation to rebuild the computer if need be. Windows.old is NOT the Windows folder renamed. This is why Disk Cleanup did not see it.

Comment: @John any reason you don't add this as an answer? Bearing in mind that the comment link has a tooltip advising us, "Avoid answering questions in comment". Or is there more to it.

Comment: I did as you suggested.

Comment: Sometimes a restart is needed before space is recovered.

Answer (score 1):

> I renamed the Windows folder to Windows.old on the old drive.

This is not a correct process.

Windows.old contains a complete installation to rebuild the computer if need be. It is created by Windows 10 when doing a feature upgrade.

Windows.old is NOT the Windows folder renamed, and this is why Disk Cleanup did not see it and remove it.

Comment: Yes, the `Windows.old` folder is created by Windows during an upgrade, in conjunction with preparing other aspects of your environment to be able to go back to the old version should you wish to. It's not a folder name users should be setting, and if we do so, the results would be unpredictable as we will not have made the associate changes Windows makes in connection with creating that folder.

Comment: I used [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dtLRjs9bnuw) video as a tutorial. It might be incorrect method but that was the only clear tutorial I could find. Also my main question here is where did the Windows folder go since it's not in the whole drive and not in the recycle bin and still it's taking space from the drive

Comment: In that tutorial, Windows.old already existed and you can use Disk Cleanup (Clean up System Files) to delete Windows.old . I have done this many times. But just to be really clear, Windows.old is an old installation, NOT the Windows folder renamed.

Comment: Understood. So what exactly did the disk cleanup do the Windows folder since I can't find it anymore? Have I completely lost it but it still takes space from the drive? And if I'm able to find it, how should I remove it properly. (Just to be clear, this whole thing is about drive I'm not using for windows anymore)

Comment: You renamed it and I am not exactly sure what happened to it. It may have been deleted as a old file, that is, regular Disk Cleanup - not the advanced cleanup that removes Windows.old.  I cannot reconstruct the error. You might turn on (enable) Hidden Files in Windows Explorer options to see it it shows up.

Comment: I have enabled hidden files and even enabled protected system files view and still haven't found anything yet. I have searched every folder on the drive that are over 20gb and none of them contain Windows.

Comment: Another approach (since an old disk) is to copy what you need to another drive, then format the disk and restore the copied items to the disk. That may be faster overall.

Comment: @MiQ I get that you intended to follow a known process but because in your case Windows.old was not already present, you have created conditions where Windows is likely to have interpreted your environment in ways you did not intend, and you are to an extent in uncharted territory. Regardless, you should be able to analyze the contents of the disk and see where the space is used. btw re. your last comment, don't just look for things called Windows or looking like Windows files to you. Assume anything could have been renamed, changed or archived. Just look to identify everything occuping space.

Comment: I ran the `chkdsk` command and it did some fixes to the drive but still unknown where the deleted files went. I also made a discovery: When checking the size of every file on the drive, it shows 179 GB but when checking the amount of used space on the drive it shows 200 GB. I thought that the remaining data would be on different partition but there was no extra partitions with size over 1 GB.

Comment: clean up chkdsk FOUND.000 chk files afterwards. boot xubuntu from pendrive [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.github.io) mount the disk and remove SystemVolumeInformation folder

Comment: I'll probably do as @John said: Copy the files to another drive and then format the disk and move the files back. It's probably the easiest and fastest method.

Comment: the discrepancy is most likely because of unaccessable files. if you don't have permissions to "read" you won't be able to "copy" too. the safest method is to overcome that permission problem with linux

Comment: @alecxs Good point. I was going to do it with linux since Windows might interfere with other file copies as well. I haven't got the time to do this yet but I'll post an update once I manage to get it done.

Comment: default setting for *System Volume Information* is 10% so it can easily occupy 20 GB